# orientation change with webview in view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, android-viewpager

I have two activities with ViewPager, first one manages Fragments with several ListViews, second one has ListView and WebView inside. both onCreate methods in activities looks the same (the only difference is pager class):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_subcat_list);

    mPager = new SubcatListPager(this);
    mPager.initialisePaging(false);
}
```

the problem occurs when I change the screen orientation. Activity with ListView fragments works fine, but the second activity creates a fragment with WebView when this line `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` is executed. and then inside pager code that fragment is created one more time. I tracked it in the debugger and two fragments with webviews are created every orientation change. I have fixed the problem by passing null instead of saved instance: `super.onCreate(null);`, but I don't think this is the right way.
is there a better way to fix this problem and restore state of the fragment I create inside ViewPager? I can use savedInstanceState and pass it to the fragments I create inside pager, but I'm not sure if passing null to the activity's parent is correct.

UPD: [ManosProm's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17905388/1417782) solves the fragment recreation issue, but now getActivity inside those fragments returns null. Quick search tells it might be caused by fragment being detached from the activity. This is my code:

```
public CommentsPager(SherlockFragmentActivity fa, Class<? extends SherlockFragment> fragment)
    {
        mFragmentActivity = fa;
        try {
            FragmentManager fm = mFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
            mContentFragment = (SherlockFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(makeFragmentTag(0));
            if (mContentFragment == null)
                mContentFragment = fragment.newInstance();

            mCommentsFragment = (CommentsListFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(makeFragmentTag(1));
            if (mCommentsFragment == null)
                mCommentsFragment = CommentsListFragment.class.newInstance();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(fa, "Pager creation failed: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    public void initialisePaging(boolean bInLayout) {

        //mFragmentActivity.setTitle(mFragmentActivity.getResources().getString(SiteContent.curr_cat.nameID));

        try {
            List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new CommentsPagerAdapter(mFragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

            if (!(mContentFragment instanceof ContentDownloader)) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(
                        "Fragment must implement content downloader interface.");
            }

            fragments.add(mContentFragment);
            fragments.add(mCommentsFragment);

            mViewPager = (ViewPager)mFragmentActivity.findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

            final ActionBar actionBar = mFragmentActivity.getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.removeAllTabs();

            mViewPager
                    .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                        }
                    });

            for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
                tab.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this);
                actionBar.addTab(tab, i == 0);
            }

            //actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(!bInLayout);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

How can I reattach fragments to the activity? Or the code is fine and I should look for the problem elsewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because on orientation change your fragments inside your viewpager are recreated so you create another fragment of the same type. But your first fragment is not destroyed and it just remains in the stack. So in the end you have one fragment for orientation Landscape and one for Portrait.

Passing null to the onCreate solves your problem because the previous fragment is not recreated, but it is just wrong as you will probably have other problems if you use this approach;

What you have to do to fix your problem is to check if the fragment already exists in the fragment manager then if it exists return that fragment or if it isn't create a new one and commit the transaction!

An example code for this is below (taken from one of my test files).

```
        MFragment fragment1;
        if (fragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewpager + ":" + 0) == null) {
            M.LogLifecycle("Fragment1", "does not exists so instantiate");
            fragment1 = MFragment.instance("Example");

        }
        else {
            M.LogLifecycle("Fragment1", "exists so retrieve instance");
            fragment1 = (MFragment) fragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewpager + ":" + 0);
        }
```

Check `"android:switcher:" + R.id.viewpager + ":" + position` which is by default the way FragmentPagerAdapter stores fragment in the FragmentManager, where R.id.viewpager is the id of your viewpager in the layout and position is the position of your fragment inside the viewpager.

I can give you only an example of how to implement it inside viewpager because you haven't added much code of your project.

*The general idea with fragments is to check if they exists in the fragmentManager before committing a transaction otherwise you may create duplicates.*

Comment: I've update my question and posted more code, please take a look

Comment: Are you using getActivity() or getSherlockActivity() inside your fragments? (Just to be sure that it is not something simple).

Comment: On a second thought, i believe that there are problems in your code and you should check again an example on how to implement a Fragment ViewPager with a FragmentPagerAdapter.